# Illustrate distance along path, like "measure distance" in Google Maps using Mapbox GL JS

Tags: distance, mapbox-gl-js

In a map in a web application, I would like to illustrate distance along a path, like how it is done with the [measure distance tool in Google Maps](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/1628031) (see attached image).

Is there a way to do this in Mapbox GL JS?

[image: Screenshot from Google Maps showing a polyline path with distance tick marks at regular intervals.]

Comment: GIS SE is a site for focused Q&A, so you have to decide what framework you want to use/ask about: Mapbox GL JS, Leaflet or Google Maps, otherwise question is most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. This really is an open question, so maybe it isn't suitable for this site. However, I split it into multiple more focused questions.